# getting unexpected element (uri:"***", local:"Site"). Expected elements are <{}Site>

Tags: jaxb, unmarshalling

I am getting

```
unexpected element (uri:"*****.xsd", local:"Site"). Expected elements are <{}Site>
```

when I am unmarshalling xml to object using JAXB:

Unmarshalling code:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(SitesHolder.class);
Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
```

My xml has:

```
 <Sites>
   <Site id="444" name="....." location="US" xmlns="*****.xsd">
::::
::::
```

SiteHolder has list of Site classes (List) and in the Site class, I have the following :

```
@XmlType(name = "", namespace="****.xsd" ,propOrder = {
        "id",
        "name",
        "location",
        "xmlns",

    })
@XmlRootElement(name = "Site")
public class Site {
]
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Can you add more code? The namespace might be significant. Don't replace text with ..... or *****. It doesn't help.

Comment: After some tweaks, I  know get unexpected element (uri:"http://example.ipsoft.com/coding.xsd", local:"Host"). Expected elements are <{}Host_Name>,<{}Load_avg_1min>,<{}IP_address>,<{}Load_avg_15min>,<{}OS>,<{}Load_avg_5min>. My class has : @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Host" )
@XmlType(name = "",  namespace="http://example.ipsoft.com/coding.xsd", propOrder = {
        "id",
        "hostName",
        "ipAddress",
        "operativeSystem",
        "loadAvg1min",
        "loadAvg5min",
        "loadAvg15min"
    })

Comment: If you need more details, I can give..

Comment: I also tried with:  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Host",namespace="http://example.ipsoft.com/coding.xsd" )
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {})
public class HostPerformance {

Comment: I figured this out. It is difficult to explain. In short, I have noticed the my object's internal structure previously does not exactly match with that of xml structure. When i fixed this, it worked!